# Unable to install tidyverse in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am fairly new to R and just updated to R 4.0

When installing tidyverse I see this:

```
There is a binary version available but the source version
  is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
broom  0.5.5  0.5.6             FALSE

package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

"suppressPackageStartupMessages(.getRequiredPackages(quietly = TRUE))
tools:::makeLazyLoading("broom", '"
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'broom'
* removing 'C:/Users/Chris' PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/broom'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
```

Then when trying to load this package

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘broom’
```

I tried independently installing broom to no avail:

```
> install.packages("broom")

  There is a binary version available but the source version
  is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
broom  0.5.5  0.5.6             FALSE

installing the source package ‘broom’

Error: unexpected string constant in:
"suppressPackageStartupMessages(.getRequiredPackages(quietly = TRUE))
tools:::makeLazyLoading("broom", '"
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'broom'
* removing 'C:/Users/Chris' PC/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/broom'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any thoughts on how to clear up this issue?

Comment: Try installing the binary version with this `install.packages("broom", type="binary")`

Comment: That worked for me, also had the same problem with one other package (withr). Thanks for the help. Would you mind briefly explaining what the issue is? I've updated R several times over the last year or so and never had this issue

Comment: The build tools used to compile and install the packages from the source code are probably getting hung up on the single quote and/or the space in your username. Installing the package from Windows binaries, instead of from source, skips this step.

On Windows, install.packages() installs from binaries if binaries for the newest version are available, but in this case the newest binaries are slightly out of date, so it tries to install from source instead. Specifying type="binary" overrides this behavior, installing the older version from the Windows binaries.

Comment: Tom, explained it better I could.  I generally always install the binary version as opposed to installing from source.  It is worth waiting a few extra days for the binary version for the incremental update.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you both for your help